# Proving a bipartite graph is never factor-critical

Tags: combinatorics

A graph is called to be factor-critical if $G-v$ has a perfect matching for any vertex $v$ of $G$.  Prove that a bipartite graph is never factor-critical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose that $G$ is bipartite, then I guess just let its two color classes consist of $m$ and $n$ vertices with the property such that $m\leq n$.

There's no way we can omit any vertex from the color class that's with $m$ elements so that resulting graph has a perfect matching.

$\therefore$We would get a bipartite graph with two color classes of different size.

Comment: Another question, how to prove that $G$ is factor-critical if and only if $G$ has an odd number of vertices and $c_o (G-S)\leq |S|$ for all nonempty set $S$ of vertices

Comment: Hey dude I can't just do all the homework for you try to figure out yourself

Comment: Well I'm having trouble

Comment: @user68067 If this is a new question then either edit the original post or start a new question. Also, please show what you've tried.

Comment: Yes exactly, this is not Chegg lmao

Comment: @user68067  $G$ is factor-critical if and only if $G$ has an odd number of vertices and $c_o(G−S)≤|S|-1$ (not $c_o(G−S)≤|S|$) for all nonempty set S of vertices